# Angular 8, jasmine <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for bind()

Tags: angular, jasmine, bind

For my Angular component, I have a base class, and in order to keep current *this context* I have following binding code. If I `console.log`, I can see `updatePreference` is called, but jasmine cannot detect if it is called.

If I use following, I am getting error at the title

```
spyOn(fixture.componentInstance.updatePreference.prototype, 'bind').and.callThrough();
```

Is there anything missing on my setup?

*Profile-component.ts extends Profile-base.ts*

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updatePreference = this.updatePreference.bind(this);
}

 public openRemovePanel(itemGuid: string) {
    super.openRemovePanel(itemGuid, this.updatePreference);
  }
```

*Profile-base.ts (base class)*

```
public openRemovePanel(itemGuid: string, callbackFunction: (id: string, data: string) => void) { 
….
callbackFunction(id, data);
}
```

*Profile-component.spec.ts*

```
fit('this should work', () => {
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);
fixture.detectChanges();

// tried both of the following
spyOn(fixture.componentInstance.updatePreference.prototype, 'bind').and.callThrough();
spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, updatePreference).and.callThrough();

…...
// make a call to openRemovePanel, and that triggers updatePreference
……

// this does not work
expect(fixture.componentInstance.updatePreference).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

After some try and fail, I noticed it works if I re-arrange order like below

```
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);

// hold the spy reference
let spyReference = spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, updatePreference).and.callThrough();

// then trigger OnInit to do binding  
fixture.detectChanges();

// then write your expection against spy reference
expect(spyReference ).toHaveBeenCalledWith('123', '456');
```